# Centering a grid with flexbox changes grid structure

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I am making a horizontal grid that contains 4 divs, I want the grid to be horizontally centered, so I wrap my grid container with another div so that it will act as a flexbox parent and try to center it (check the code below), while the grid has been centered the horizontal grid has now become a vertical grid

**HTML:**

```
<h2>My Simple Grid</h2>
<div class="grid-holder">
<div class="grid-container grid-container--fill">
  <div class="grid-element">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    4
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
}

.grid-container--fill {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-element {
  background-color: darkGreen;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.grid-holder{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

Current Result:
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB71o.png)

Expected Outcome:
Grid elements 1,2,3,4 should remain horizontal while the grid-holder div remains centered, sorry for the bad drawing
[my drawing of expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA6rB.png)

I also want to know why did I need to use flex-direction: column ? Am I making any silly mistake, or forgot the basics ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your issue is down to your use of auto-fill. It means that, whilst you have only added 4 grid items yourself, there are potentially many more than 4 columns. Your grid will create as many 100px columns as will fit on the screen, expanding them slightly to ensure the grid takes up the full width available. Basically your grid is always centred (in a sense) but your grid items just sit in the first 4 available columns.

Comment: Do you have to use `display: grid;` or can you also afford to change it to `display: flex;`?

Comment: as said Andrew, just change grid-container--fill by:  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px, 1fr));

Answer (score 1):

After you added `align-items: center;` to your flex container `grid-holder`, And with `grid-template-columns` set to `auto-fill` for the class `grid-container--fill` many columns are implicitly created with each item to fill the whole row with as many columns as it can, then the elements will be centred but only one element will be shown in a row, To fix that change the `auto-fill` by 4 to precise the number of columns that should be displayed in each row as follow:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
}

.grid-container--fill {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-element {
  background-color: darkGreen;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.grid-holder{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Simple Grid</h2>
<div class="grid-holder">
  <div class="grid-container grid-container--fill">
    <div class="grid-element">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```